# Python .readline() reset

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

In Python 3.4/Asyncio I'm using StreamReader/Writer.

To detect a client disconnect the common method seems to be to read from the client and if there's nothing there then the client disconnected.

```
while True:
    data = (yield from asyncio.wait_for(client_reader.readline(),
                                   timeout=1.0))
    if not data: #client disconnected
        break
```

However quickly you run out of lines to read from the client header (it moves to the next line on each loop) and if there are no additional lines sent from the client (in my case the client is not sending just listening) you hit the timeout.

What I would like to do is to only read the first line of the header over and over.. or possibly even just the first character of the first line, or if that's not possible when it gets to the last line loop back around to the first.

What's the best/most elegant way to accomplish this task? 3.4/Asyncio/StreamReader/Writer. (detecting client disconnects)

Comment: I think the problem is not asyncio specific and maybe requires change of client code. 
How do you like to solve it "in general", without asyncio?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The way that worked for me was to check for EOF first and then raise a ConnectionError exception if true. So for your code I would add the following:

```
while True:

    try:
        if client_reader.at_eof():
            raise ConnectionError

        data = (yield from asyncio.wait_for(client_reader.readline(),
                                       timeout=1.0))
        if not data: #client disconnected
            break

    except ConnectionError:
        break

    except:
        break # This is here to catch things like the asyncio futures timeout exception
```

Hope that helps. If anyone has a better way I'd be interested.